# "Operation Not Permitted" - Cannot get read access from App created with Automator Bash Script

Tags: bash, macos, jq, file-permissions, automator

I am stuck trying to access this specific file from an App I have created with Automator. When the exact same Bash script is run from Terminal, all is dandy. I have checked permissions on the file and they are `-rw-r--r--@` (which I recognize is quarantined) and then I remove the xattr so it becomes `-rw-r--r--`, however it does seem that the attribute does get reapplied at some point (not instantaneous).

The file path is the following:

`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.findmy.fmipcore/Items.data: Operation not permitted`

and the application I am creating is documented here on github
https://github.com/jbobrow/DogWalker

As a quick recap of what I've tried:
I tried changing the file permissions. I tried restarting after permission changes. I granted the application full access in System Settings. I tried removing the quarantine attribute from the file...

When the application is run in Automator or with the app, the file isn't accessed so the CSV simply gets a blank line with the date. When I run the same bash script in Terminal, the CSV populates as desired.

I look forward to a possible solution and will be thrilled to give credit in my README.md

Comment: Does your script work if called from launchd?  Do you really need Automator?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have selinux enabled? Find out by running `getenforce`. If it returns "Enforcing" then it could be what is blocking access to the file.

You can disable the enforcement with `sudo setenforce 0`. To confirm it isn't being enforced, just run `getenforce` again. It should return "Passive".

You can use `sudo setenforce 1` to re-enable. Note these that changes are temporary in that upon next reboot it will go back to the default that is set in the /etc/sysconfig/selinux file.

If you find that selinux is enabled, Google search "how to diagnose selinux issues" for instructions on how to resolve issues.

Comment: Since this is tagged “macos” I would assume no selinux